# backbone.js basic questions

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    el: $('body'),

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
       this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<ul> <li>Hello Yupeee</li> </ul>");
    }
  });

  var listView = new ListView();      
})(jQuery);
```

1. Why do we pass jQuery as argument.
2. what does `el: $('body')` mean?
3. what does  `_.bindAll(this, 'render');` do?
4. Let's suppose i need another element, lets take Text Field or something... how would i go with it... should i add all in render function...
5. Should i know JQuery before i go with backbone.js

Answer (score 3):

1. We are scoping jQuery object to $ inside the self executing
   anonymous function. So that inside the function there are no conflicts with other libraries that might be using $ variable.
2. In backbone, views bind themselves to an html dom element. If it is not specified it is empty 'div'. So in this case it is referring to body.
3. It will make sure that the calls to the render method are called in correct context 'this', which you want to be current view object.
4. Usually you create a template, by using underscore templating engine or anyone by your choice. You can also create html elements as string also, backbone doesn't really care in any case. Then you bind it to the view as the el. By either compiling the template or straight up html.
5. You should know javascript well enough, event bindings in general and jQuery selectors at minimum. Although backbone says you don't need jQuery, but it is definitely good to know.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding in **3**. I don't think `bindAll` is related with _event binding_.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Updated it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is doing this syntax is something like `$ = jQuery` before start executing the block.
2. It is gonna initialize `this.el` pointing to the DOM element `body`.
3. It will modify the calls to the `render` method so the `(render.context).this` will be always the actual `this`. [Check Underscore's bindAll documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll). This sounds weird but in JS the context if very *volatile* :)
4. Yes, but [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766187/js-templating-system-with-backbone-js/9771078#9771078) can be helpful.
5. It helps, also [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore).